# Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am getting following error when I open my site which is made using laravel 5

> Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\cms\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

I have tried removing vendor folder and `composer.lock` file and running composer install it's not working I tried running PHP artisan optimize but it shows error

> Fatal error: Class'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Edited:
This problem aroused as soon as I used the `php artisan make:model Page` command which did create the model but then the above error gets displayed when I access the site
Also If use the Laravel's Local Development Server no such problem arises only if I use wamp server

Comment: Do you see this class present in vendor folder?

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: yes it is present in vendor folder

Comment: i have tried composer dump-autoload

Comment: Probably you have a compiled file. Try running ```php artisan clear-compiled```

Comment: remove `/bootstrap/start.php`, `composer.lock`, and the `vendor` and run `composer install`

Comment: php artisan clear-compiled shows the same error Iluminate\Foundation\Appication not found

Comment: there is no start.php file inside bootstrap folder @K.Toress

Comment: @xenish did you ever get this error solved?

Answer (score 114):

In my situation, I didn't have the full vendor dependencies in place (composer file was messed up during original install) - so running any artisan commands caused a failure.

I was able to use the `--no-scripts` flag to prevent artisan from executing before it was included.  Once my dependencies were in place, everything worked as expected.

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Comment: +1 Worked for me. In my case I have included other required packages separately in the composer.json file. This helped me.

Comment: Also worked for me using "composer update --no-scripts" (after running "composer dump-autoload")

Answer (score 52):

Just in case I trip over this error in 2 weeks again...
My case: Checkout an existing project via git and pull in all dependencies via composer. Came down to the same error listed within the title of this post.

Solution:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer install --no-scripts
```

make sure everything works now as expected (no errors!)

```
composer update
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, was going around this for about two hours, trying other answers from stack, but this totally solved it. Easy and to the point. Thanks

Comment: This works for me, encounter this issues after migrating Laravel website to another server

Comment: in my case ," composer dump-autoload" didn't worked but instead "composer install --no-scripts" was so fine!

Answer (score 9):

Something is clearly corrupt in your Laravel setup and it is very hard to track without more info about your environment. Usually these 2 commands help you resolve such issues

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

If nothing else helps then I recommend you to install fresh Laravel 5 app and copy your application logic over, it should take around 15 min or so.

Answer (score 7):

Easy as this, that worked for my project

- Delete */vendo*r folder
- and execute `composer install`
- then run project `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 4):

In my case composer was not installed in that directory. So I run

```
composer install
```

then error resolved.

**or you can try**

```
composer update --no-scripts
cd bootstrap/cache/->rm -rf *.php
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this problem (Different Case with same error),
The answer above I tried may not work because My case were different but produced the same error.
I think my vendor libraries were jumbled,
I get this error by:

1. Pull from remote git, master branch is codeigniter then  I do composer update on master branch, I wanted to work on laravel branch then I checkout and do composer update so I get the error,

> Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in
>   C:\cms\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Solution:
I delete the project on local and do a clone again, after that I checkout to my laravel file work's branch and do composer update then it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had accidentally commented out:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

in
    /public/index.php

When pasting in some debugging statements.

Answer (score 1):

For latest laravel version also check your version because I was also
facing this error but after update latest php version, I got rid from
this error.

Answer (score 1):

**run** `composer require laravel/framework` **after** `composer install` **then** `php artisan key:generate` **its work for me in kali linux**

Comment: Your answer must have an interpretive example along with your code, after all this question is old ...

Answer (score 0):

please test below solution:

- first open command prompt `cmd ==> window+r` and go to the location where laravel installed.
- try `composer require laravel/laravel`

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that anyone else reading this is a stupid as I was but just in case...
I had accidentally removed "laravel/framework": "^5.6" from my composer.json when resolving merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

i was having same problem with this error.
It turn out my Kenel.php is having a wrong syntax when i try to comply with wrong php8 syntax

The line should be

```
protected $commands = [
    //
];
```

instead of

```
protected array $commands = [
        //
];
```

Answer (score 0):

@kalhan-toress 's comment is what ACTUALLY WORKED FOR ME

remove `/bootstrap/start.php`,`composer.lock`, and the `vendor` and run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused on initial deployment because I didn't have a `.env` file in that directory (because those don't belong on Github where the files were transferred from).

Answer (score 0):

check your .env file i think you miss something. Maybe like this

[image]

if yes then need to add manually and composer update or install composer

Comment: .env? You mean `package.json`?