# php artisan serve can't find the autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

**SOLUTION:** `laravel new project-name` was actually giving me an error that i overlooked. I had the wrong version of php. It **requires** phpv7.1.3 or higher. If you don't have it it doesn't work.

Ran into one other problem:

- i had a system environment variable that is pointing to an old version of php
- Also laravel requires openssl extension and mbstring to turned on. UNCOMMENTED from php.ini

FOR NEWCOMERS: if you have just downloaded php and unzipped the file. It contains a file called

> install.txt

that you **HAVE** to read. It explains everything.

I ran `laravel new blog` from their getting started page. When I tried to run  `php artisan serve`, I got the following error:

> Warning: require(C:\Projects\laravel-projects\blog/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Projects\laravel-projects\blog\artisan on line 18

The artisan file is pointing to

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

this directory does not exist. Even if I point it to the correct directory, it still wouldn't work because I don't have read permissions for that folder (so it gets denied).

What's going on, and how can I fix this?

EDIT: changed the url from the mentioned above to:

> C:\Users\sarkis\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\autoload.php

This worked perfectly for some reason.
And NOW. A **NEW ERROR** HAS APPEARED.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\Projects\laravel-projects\blog\bootstrap\app.php:14
>   Stack trace:#0 C:\Projects\laravel-projects\blog\artisan(21): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Projects\laravel-projects\blog\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

found that i don't have the proper version of php required.

Comment: Did you run composer install?

Comment: yes i did and the vendor file did not show up using windows 10 btw

Comment: @CharbelSarkis Change permissions for your installation directory... You need to have, read, write, modify and for running locally execute also... Then run composer install and all should be fine...

Comment: You running WAMPP/XAMPP or ISS?

Comment: Wamp. I have wamp and xampp which should i use.

Comment: I think you are in windows OS ?

Comment: yes @C2486 windows 10

Comment: try with `'\'` instead `'/'` here `require __DIR__.'\vendor\autoload.php';`

Comment: that folder doesn't even exist. The problem is i have installed laravel globally. When you run `laravel new project` it doesn't make your vendor folder. I just tried installing laravel without `global` and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running laravel new project_name. It outputted the text php 7.1.3 or higher needs to be installed. Current version 5.6 does not match requirements. And it aborts without plainly giving you an error.  Be sure to download php version 7.1.3 or higher. Also check if you have environment variables for earlier versions of php and delete those.

> note: be sure to read install.txt from the php download

Answer (score 5):

1. First Install Composer: **composer install**.
2. Then run a command in CMD prompt: **composer dump-autoload**.

Comment: i have composer. that's how i installed laravel **composer global require laravel/installer**

Comment: @Charbel
Well that command won't install composer as of course you didn't expect to be able to install composer via composer, did you? That will install all the "dependencies" for your project that are missing for some reason, using composer and the `composer.json` file in root path of your project.
So just do this:
In the root path of your project, run `composer install`.
Remember you have to run this in the path that the `composer.json` file of your project is located which in this case, will always be the root dir of your laravel project. It will download and install all the dependencies.
Y

Comment: @arm That wasn't the problem. Apparently laravel **requires** php 7.2 from that point in time. And i had a much older version.

Answer (score 2):

Try running **composer dump-autoload** , after that run a **composer install**

If that doesn't work, try the **composer update --no-scripts**

Comment: `Generating optimized autoload files
Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script
> @php artisan package:discover

Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\Projects\laravel-projects\blog\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255`

Comment: this is the error that i got from `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: `php artisan serve` after running this command  `Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\Projects\laravel-projects\blog\bootstrap\app.php on line 14`

Comment: Check this post then -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Laravel, and I got the same confusion with the command:

```
laravel new blog
```

There was no vendor folder.

But after I tried:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

I found the vendor folder came up.

Don't know why either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try install via `Composer Create-Project`:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything the file still points to an empty directory. Had to change the url to the correct one and got a new error

Answer (score -1):

Check all your permissions to following folders and give 0777 permissions

```
storage 0777
vendor 0777
bootstrap/cache 0777
```

And then run again

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: He uses Windows.

Comment: i do have permissions for the files it's just that the vendor folder doesn't exist and even if it did the actual folder that this needs is located in appdata/...../vendor/autoload