# Fatal error: Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat-app\app\Events\NewMessage.php on line 14

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

Using Pusher with Laravel 5.8 to send messages in real-time generates this error on NewMessage Event file.
Steps I took to try and debug:

1. tried removing the line "use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;" inside the Class;
2. tried without using the Classes at the top of the file

none of those worked. On Laravel 5.8 Documentation they don't mention using this line inside our Event Classes, maybe it's outdated?!

File looks like this:

`

```
namespace StyxEminus\Events;
use StyxEminus\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $message;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Message $message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('messages.' . $this->message->to);
}

public function broadcastWith() {
    return ["message" => $this->message];
}
}`
```

Local Server: Apache on Xampp;
Operating System: W10 64bit
Browser: Brave(chromium) & Chrome

Comment: composer dump can help

Comment: @Dry7 the output looks like this: Generated optimized autoload files containing 3638 classes
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision

Comment: Is the error still left?

Comment: Yes the error still persists

Comment: composer update --no-scripts
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found

Comment: Doing that removed barryvdh/laravel-cors & asm89/stack-cors, the public directory gives another error: "Class 'Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider' not found" and the initial error is still there

Answer (score 0):

you need import **Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable**

Comment: you import another file

Comment: Thanks for your answers but now it's the same error but with the new Class in Bus

Comment: you delete use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;?

Comment: Yes, and replaced it with your suggestion