# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/khadija/InstProject/bootstrap/app.php:14

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel php framework ,whenever i try to run `php artisan`
i got this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/khadija/InstProject/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/khadija/InstProject/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/khadija/InstProject/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you install the composer dependencies? (In other words: do you have a `vendor` folder, filled with other folders?) If not, you need to do `composer install`

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found) help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't download laravel the traditional way by running `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-app-name` or `laravel new my-app-name`(if you have the laravel/installer installed globally on your system. Then you need to run `composer install` or `composer update`.

If this solves your problem then you might run into another problem, at this point, you should generate an `APP_KEY` by running `php artisan key:generate`