# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have several issue to running my code. The last thing that still not solve is

> Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

I do

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

but still have the same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found)

Comment: Did you install laravel? Or did you run composer install?

Comment: I run composer install dude

Comment: Are you including the Composer autoloader? `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` (See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Comment: @md2perpe, Do I need to write: `php composer.phar update`  ?

Comment: @md2perpe terminal give me `Could not open input file: composer.phar`

Comment: I don't know whether you need to update Composer. I know that you need to include the Composer autoloader in the main script. Are you doing that?

Comment: @md2perpe That should be handled by Laravel

Comment: I'd remove the `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` and run `composer install` again. Make sure there are no errors