# How to setup laravel using laragon in windows

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laragon

[image]

There is error:

```
Warning: require(C:\laragon\www\sprii\public/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\laragon\www\sprii\public\index.php on line 34

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\sprii\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in C:\laragon\www\sprii\public\index.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\sprii\public\index.php on line 34
```

I try to `composer update` and comes out this error. why?

After try to run "composer dump-autoload", come out this error

```
Generating optimized autoload files
Class App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\TwoFactorApiController located in C:/laragon/www/sprii/app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\TwoFactorApiController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in C:\laragon\www\sprii\bootstrap\app.php:14
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\laragon\www\sprii\artisan(20): require_once()
    #1 {main}
      thrown in C:\laragon\www\sprii\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
    Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

Comment: did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: I did, after composer install it will advice me to composer update，then i follow instruction composer update still come out error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `compose.lock` file.

Right-click on laragon icon in system tray and thick extensions:

```
Laragon->PHP->Extensions->Sodium & pdo_sqlite
```

[image: enabling php extensions]

Run `cmd` as administrator and then run these:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
composer dump-autoload
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in C:\laragon\www\sprii\bootstrap\app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\sprii\artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\laragon\www\sprii\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Comment: the first or second command thrown this?

Comment: The second throw this

Comment: Can you add your composer.json content in your question?

Comment: The error content in my question now. am i misunderstand your meaning?

Comment: I installed laragon. downloaded latest laravel from github! And an composer install [this image](https://freeimage.host/i/HX5zDIs) was the output as it should be! compose update runs ok! so there is a problem with your first command! we should find ansd solve that!

Comment: Do you mean my first command is "composer install" that step ?

Comment: Yes, is your output same as my image?

Comment: I got uploaded an error image, please refer it.

Comment: just remove your `compose.lock` file.

Comment: I just deleted compose.lock file. there is another error  "No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information."

Comment: this is not an error! its ok. now is the output of command `composer update` different?

Comment: After run `composer install` there is having an error as image that i show you, then i run again `composer update` still the same result.

Comment: try `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` and check the answer updated again!

Comment: @SeewpengNea if my answer was helpful please accpet it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Generating optimized autoload files Class App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\TwoFactorApiController located in C:/laragon/www/sprii/app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\TwoFactorApiController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping. Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script

The issue is that you are not using proper naming convention for PSR-4.

Your file structure is  `app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\TwoFactorApiController.php`

Namespace should be
`App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\TwoFactorApiController` ✅

Your current namespace is `App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\TwoFactorApiController` which is wrong.

Refactor the namespace and you won't see this message.

Comment: Can i know how to refactor the namespace?

Comment: try this: `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Open the file and look at the top