# Xampp reinstall but php version does not change

Tags: php, xampp

Newly installed xampp still showing old removed xampp php version in mac os

Hi
My peviouse xampp php version is 7.3 and i removed it. Then i re installed new xampp with PHP version is 7.2.

But still php-v showing as 7.3.why is that? How to fix it?
I am using mac os 10.15

Comment: You probably have a separate PHP installation from MacOS that's invoked in shell. I'd expect `phpinfo()` to show the currently installed version with XAMPP. Why would you install such an ancient version, though?

Comment: hi @MarkusAO I have an project to setup which use php 7.2.can you help me to sort out this?

Comment: Have you tried to run it on PHP 8.x? At least use the latest 7.4. Version 7.2 has been EOL since 11/2020. Using unsupported old version exposes you to potential security issues and other bugs. Upgrading your project from 7 to 8 shouldn't be very complicated. [See the migration guides](https://www.php.net/eol.php).

Comment: I don't have permission to upgrade the project at the moment.just trying fix some bugs in it by staying with this version

Comment: I tried with version 7.3  it says Illuminate/Foundation/Application  not found error @MarkusAO

Comment: Right so the project is also stuck with an old version of Laravel. Do search for any errors you get, [Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found).